# Ubuntu 13.04 fan noise

Tags: ati, fan, hybrid-graphics

I've installed Ubuntu 13.04 along with Windows 7 x64, and its fan noise is unbearable (no such noise when operating with Windows 7).
Here's the laptop specs http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/d...name=c02993732 .

It used to overheat with almost anything, so I followed this guide as many people said it's probably that the hybrid GPU isn't supported well by the open-source drivers http://xpressrazor.wordpress.com/201...-linux-ubuntu/ .
Currently I put the AMD one on action rather than the integrated Intel one, it's much better than before but still it's very bad relative to Windows 7. It produces loud noise with just browsing.

Another not so important issue, it has a black screen when it boots and doesn't go away unless i press the increase illumination button (once).

If anyone has a recommendation for a fix that would make it operates like Windows7 I would appreciate it. Is Ubuntu's unity is the problem? Do I need another Linux OS other than Ubuntu?
Does everyone do this hassle to use Ubuntu or this hardware issue is not common?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can adjust your fan settings with the package  `fancontrol`

To setup use `pwmconfig`.

Comment: I don't want it to overheat, the fan is loud for a reason, I'm trying to fix that reason

Comment: `fancontrol` works together with temperature sensors, so you can exactly adapt the speed of your fan to match your desired requirements. This soft was created to prevent overheating. So you'll hear fan noise only when the CPU reaches the temperature limit.